# how connect mysql using c++

Tags: c++, mysql

*Editor's Note: Original Text:*

how connect mysql using c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "/usr/local/mysql5/include/mysql.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    MYSQL *mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    string server = "192.168.1.92";
    string username = "useradmin";
    string password = "useradmin";
    string database = "market";
    int port = 3306;

    mysql = mysql_init(0);
    if ( !mysql_real_connect( mysql, server.c_str(), username.c_str(), password.c_str(), database.c_str(), port, NULL, 0 ) ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error( mysql ) );
        return 0;
    }
    if ( !mysql_query( mysql, "SELECT text, prequency FROM ma_dict" ) ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error( mysql ) );
        return 0;
    }

    result = mysql_use_result( mysql );
    ofstream SaveFile("/tmp/dict.txt");

    while ( ( row = mysql_fetch_row( result ) ) != NULL ) {
        //SaveFile << fprintf( stdout, "%s\t%d", row[0], $row[1] ) << endl;
        cout << row[0] << endl;
    }

    mysql_free_result( result );
    mysql_close( mysql );
    SaveFile.close();

    return 1;
```

}

undefined reference to `mysql_init'
undefined reference to`mysql_real_connect'
...

---

*Editor's Note: A translation was attempted:*

I'm using Eclipse, and I get compilation errors using `mysql.h`. How do I link to `mysql`?

```
#include "mysql.h"
```

---

*Editor's Note: [English questions are required on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow). Please do your best at translating your question to English as needed, even if you have to use an automatic translation service like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).*

Comment: sorry,my english is poor

Comment: Seems enough to translate it in English.

Comment: @cheeming, google translate gives a pretty good translation of what you've said. I can even tell you that you'd need to provide the error message you're getting.

Comment: I speak some Chinese, so I've done the translation.

Comment: @BoltClock Translate the answer then, too ;)

Comment: @cheeming: My Chinese is even poorer.

Comment: @cheeming - if you don't understand English, you'll not understand the answers then.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Man please, questions on Stack Overflow aren't required to be in English. T_T

Comment: @WTP: [Actually, English is required](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow). Although I don't think the downvotes are called for, seeing that I can figure out what the question is via Google Translate.

Comment: @In silico mmm somewhere else I read it wasn't. :)

Comment: It's totally required. OK, voted to reopen and reverted down vote, as it's translated.

Comment: @GSerg: In silico did a better job to be honest :P

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm not even fluent in Chinese, to be honest. Certainly not enough to translate a computer programming question. Google Translate and context FTW. :-P

Comment: @In silico: Yeah but my translation was much cruder!

Answer (score 0):

*Editor's Note: Original Text:*

信息太少了, 把编译器错误贴出来看看.
可能因为:

- mysql.h不在配置的include目录中.
- Mysql库文件不在link列表里面
- 头文件与二进制库文件不配套

---

*Editor's Note: A translation was attempted:*

There's too little information in your question. Post the actual compiler error into your question.

That being said, the error may be caused by:

- `Mysql.h` is not in the configuration or in the include directory.
- MySql database file is not in the linker's path.
- Header and library files are not consistent with each other.

Comment: @In silico: Editor's note should be a comment. You already have one under the question anyway :)

Comment: Please note that [English answers are required on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow). Please do your best at translating your answer to English as needed, even if you have to use an automatic translation service like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).

Comment: The third hint means header files are not consistent with the library ("不配套" means "not consistent" or "not compatible").

Comment: @neuront: I'm not fluent in Chinese, so thanks for the heads up. I've edited the post.

Comment: Thanks @In Silico for translating my answer.
I didn't notice the English is required and I saw the question was in Chinese, so made the mistake.
I would not do that again.

Answer (score 0):

An issue in the sample is that `mysql_query` returns 0 on SUCCESS – so it always thinks an error occurred on success.

Change it to:

```
if ( mysql_query( mysql, "SELECT text, prequency FROM ma_dict" ) ) {
```